# Space disappears on transferring via wcf (xml)

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have an object `A` with property `Name` that I use in WCF to transfer a model (communication).

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "p0", Order = 0)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I discoverd that when `Name` starts with a space ' 123' then after deserialisation on the other side it has lost the space and it became '123'.

The WCF service uses MTOM message encoding.

Is this a known effect for xml or wcf in general?

With the help of the answer provided I discovered that leading whitespaces are removed due to the Mtom encoding. Indeed when I remove Mtom the leading whitespaces are correctly transferred.

The security configuration did not play any role in my scenario.

Is there some way to avoid it?

Comment: You have to XML encode the name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Comment: Never heard of such a thing, and would be astounded if that would be anything else than a bug. Are both, client and server, actually .NET using WCF?

Comment: @KevinRaffay certainly not. The (Net)DataContractSerializer ("WCF") will do that for you.

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5e1dd95-5d85-4eab-a644-ed89b8d47cc6/wcfxmlserializer-leading-spaces-on-xmltext-field-are-trimmed) MSDN forum post seems relevant. According to that post it's an issue on the deserialization side and they worked around it by prepending superfluous characters before serializing then manually finding and remove them when deserializing. Similar information [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1082877/How-do-i-pass-a-whitespace-as-parameter), roughly "an issue with .NET 4.5, workaround by using special whitespace characters".

Comment: @Christian.K it certainly is .NET 4.5.1 WCF, When it is a bug like Quantic mentions it would be interesting to know whether it is possible to fix this in a general way e.g. by overriding (de)serialization for string properties?

Comment: Do you use the XmlSerializer? By default WCF uses DataContractSerializer.

Comment: DataContractSerializer

Comment: [meta-info] One could argue this is a duplicat of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6066932/21567), but since there was never a workaround provided, but only stated that is is (was?) a bug, this question should not be closed as a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Replaced answer since it is clear that you're using MTOM.

Apparently this is a [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/619894/strings-stripped-of-leading-whitespace-when-using-mtom-message-encoding) in WCF, that according to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4cfd1cd6-a038-420d-8cb5-ec5a2628df1a/string-serialization-issue-with-wcf-40?forum=wcf) is marked as 'Deferred'. So it is hard say, when it will be fixed. The last link also mentions some workarounds, which I will reproduce here, so that they don't get lost.

1. Don't use MTOM
2. Add some prefix character that both sender and receiver know about and that the receiver can then strip off (like quotes, etc.).
3. Use a message inspector and buffer the message

The code below shows the third workaround for this issue:

```
public class Post_4cfd1cd6_a038_420d_8cb5_ec5a2628df1a
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Echo(string text);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string Echo(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In service, text = {0}", ReplaceControl(text));
            return text;
        }
    }
    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        //var result = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None) { MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text };
        var result = new BasicHttpBinding() { MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom };
        return result;
    }
    static string ReplaceControl(string text)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in text)
        {
            if ((' ' <= c && c <= '~') && c != '\\')
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("\\u{0:X4}", (int)c);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public class MyInspector : IEndpointBehavior, IDispatchMessageInspector, IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            request = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue).CreateMessage();
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            reply = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue).CreateMessage();
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), GetBinding(), "");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyInspector());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyInspector());
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        string input = "\t\tDoc1\tCase1\tActive";
        string output = proxy.Echo(input);
        Console.WriteLine("Input = {0}, Output = {1}", ReplaceControl(input), ReplaceControl(output));
        Console.WriteLine("input == output: {0}", input == output);

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Again, real answer and code are from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4cfd1cd6-a038-420d-8cb5-ec5a2628df1a/string-serialization-issue-with-wcf-40?forum=wcf).

Comment: It is HTTP with MTOM `binding name="BasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Mtom"`

Comment: And also `security mode="None"` which is mentiod in your second link.

Comment: So, there you have it ;-)

Comment: The link of it being a confirmed bug is dead however.

Comment: Yeah Microsoft's connect site... :-(

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant information (that you're using `MTOM` binding w/o security) and that you know it at least was a bug (referencing the links (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/58101c0e-5c9b-43fd-8acb-becfd0d3e486/strings-stripped-of-leading-whitespace-when-using-mtom-message-encoding?forum=wcf) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066932/why-does-wcf-remove-whitespace-in-text-field-when-security-is-set-to-none/6072405#6072405). You should also rephrase the question, if there is any new info on this bug/a workaround (since connect is dead).

Comment: I can confirm that solutions 1 and 3 work. Solution 2 will of course also work but to me looks unpractical. Solution 3 only needs the client side part. I prefer to have two classes on the client side `class InspectBehavior : IEndpointBehavior` and `class ClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector`. In `ApplyClientBehavior` of `InspectBehavior` you add the `ClientMessageInspector `.