# Leading whitespaces disappear with WCF MTOM

Tags: c#, wcf, mtom

According to this post...

[Space disappears on transferring via wcf (xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639242/space-disappears-on-transferring-via-wcf-xml)

... there is a configrmed bug, when sending a string with leading spaces (e.g.    `foo` using an MTOM binding in WCF. The leading spaces will not be preserved.

I tried to fix the bug using the given suggestion but had no luck yet. Here is my code:

**The binding that we use:**

```
<binding name="foo_wsHTTPbinding_MitSSL_MTOM" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" closeTimeout="00:01:00" messageEncoding="Mtom">
    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

**The code that we added:**

**Inside the config:**

```
<extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="preserveLeadingSpacesBehavior" type="Core.ServiceBase.PreserveLeadingSpacesBehaviorExtensionElement, Core.ServiceBase"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>[...]</serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        [...]
        <behavior>
            <preserveLeadingSpacesBehavior />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**PreserveLeadingSpacesBehaviorExtensionElement.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace Core.ServiceBase
{
    public class PreserveLeadingSpacesBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new PreserveLeadingSpacesBehavior();
        }

        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(PreserveLeadingSpacesBehavior); }
        }
    }

    public class PreserveLeadingSpacesBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new PreserveLeadingSpacesInspector());
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }
    }

    public class PreserveLeadingSpacesInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            request = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue).CreateMessage();
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

According to the blog post [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4cfd1cd6-a038-420d-8cb5-ec5a2628df1a/string-serialization-issue-with-wcf-40?forum=wcf), this should resolve the problem.

But it is not working so far. When setting a breakpoint, it gets hit in `AfterReceiveRequest` and I see in the message, that the spaces are still there, but in my service method, it disappeared.

Heres my test method on the server site:

```
public string Foo(string bar)
{
    return bar;
}
```

Do you have any idea, why it could still not work?

Comment: Are you sure you have applied preserveLeadingSpacesBehavior to the service? I think preserveLeadingSpacesBehavior may not be successfully applied to the service.

Comment: @DingPeng It hit the breakpoint and I saw the correct message there in `AfterReceiveRequest`. After pressing F5, I hit the secondary breakpoint in my message and saw, that the bar-string was "trimmed".

Comment: * secondary breakpoint in my service-method `Foo`

Comment: I tested it according to the example in the link, and I didn't find any problems, it works normally. Do you mean if the space disappears after the client calls the Foo method? One solution is not to use MTOM.

Comment: Thats the bug. The space disappears. Disabling MTOM means, in general, bigger messages and we don't like that, because our biggest bottleneck is the network right now, our servers are fine.

Comment: This is an issue but we can solve it through the message inspector.